# Why is there Messenger icon in App drawer?

Tags: google-plus

I have Google Plus app installed on my HTC One X. In the App drawer it shows icons for Google+ and Messenger. Both these belong to same Google+ app. The Messenger icon opens up Google+ app with message displayed `Update to Hangouts. Go to the app` and I have Hangouts installed.

The Messenger app icon looks like this:

[image: Messenger App icon]

I tried to uninstall Messenger and it uninstalled the updates of entire Google Plus app. It seems the Messenger icon is created by Google Plus and it only asks user to go to Hangout.

Why is this extra icon present? Is there any way to get rid of it?

Comment: I have it too on a Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2. My guess is legacy code that hasn't yet been removed for the people that haven't yet updated.

Comment: Several launchers (e.g. Nova, Apex, and GoLauncher) have the possibility to hide apps from the drawer. You might want to check for that feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to worry. [As of Google+ v4.1](https://plus.google.com/101870761930221849874/posts/HNSJByBhDin), this is going away.

> **5. Messenger is going away, Hangouts is sticking around**
>   Now that Hangouts provides messaging and video calls across Android, iOS and the web, we’re removing Messenger from the Google+ mobile apps (first on Android, then on iOS). Later today you'll be able to download all of your Messenger conversations (including text and photos) from Google Takeout.

The new app is rolling out now and you should have it in the next few days.